# multiple processes

Tags: mysql

I am using openSUSE & mysql table with 25 million records.

I am doing some stress testing & came accross something: I am running 2 perl scripts that access mysql....each will select a record one at a time at random then get another record & so on. So far, so good. Let's call these process A & process B.

Now, I want to kick it up a notch. When I add a third process (process C) that selects all records (either through perl or phpmyadmin) then process A & process B freeze up until process C finishes.

Shouldn't I be able to make concurrent requests?

Comment: this depends of mysql transactions. also depends of your mysql configuration.

Comment: Are those A&B processes doing some update on the records?